# Cannot read source map from nonstandard location

Tags: typescript, webpack, source-maps

I am having trouble getting source maps to work with Webpack and TypeScript, when my sources/bundles are in non standard locations.  If they are in the standard `./src` and `./dist` folders, everything works fine.  If I move my source files to and reference my bundles from `./Scripts/src` and `./Scripts/dist`, respectively, I get the following error:

```
SourceMap http://localhost:56154/Scripts/dist/bundle.js.map read failed: One or more errors occurred..
```

The only thing I have changed between working and not working is the `Scripts` directory.

Specifically, here are the relevant files before and after the changes:

**Before (Working)**

*webpack.config.js*

```
'use strict';

const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    mode: 'development',
    context: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.ts', '.tsx']
    },
    entry: "./index.tsx",
    output: {
        publicPath: '/dist/',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },

    // Enable sourcemaps for debugging webpack's output.
    devtool: "source-map",

    module: {
        rules: [
            // All files with a '.ts' or '.tsx' extension will be handled by 'awesome-typescript-loader'.
            { test: /\.tsx?$/, loader: "awesome-typescript-loader" },

            // All output '.js' files will have any sourcemaps re-processed by 'source-map-loader'.
            { enforce: "pre", test: /\.js$/, loader: "source-map-loader" }
        ]
    },
    externals: {
        "react": "React",
        "react-dom": "ReactDOM"
    }
};
```

*tsconfig.json*

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "outDir": "./dist/",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "module": "commonjs",
        "target": "es5",
        "lib": ["es5", "es6", "dom"],
        "jsx": "react"
    },
    "include": [
        "./src/**/*"
    ]
}
```

*Default.aspx*

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    ...
</head>
<body>
    ...

    <div id="example"></div>

    <!-- Dependencies -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./node_modules/react/umd/react.development.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./node_modules/react-dom/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

    <!-- Main -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./dist/bundle.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

**After**

*webpack.config.js*

```
'use strict';

const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    mode: 'development',
    context: path.resolve(__dirname, 'Scripts/src'),
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.ts', '.tsx']
    },
    entry: "./index.tsx",
    output: {
        publicPath: '/Scripts/dist/',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, './Scripts/dist'),
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },

    // Enable sourcemaps for debugging webpack's output.
    devtool: "source-map",

    module: {
        rules: [
            // All files with a '.ts' or '.tsx' extension will be handled by 'awesome-typescript-loader'.
            { test: /\.tsx?$/, loader: "awesome-typescript-loader" },

            // All output '.js' files will have any sourcemaps re-processed by 'source-map-loader'.
            { enforce: "pre", test: /\.js$/, loader: "source-map-loader" }
        ]
    },
    externals: {
        "react": "React",
        "react-dom": "ReactDOM"
    }
};
```

*tsconfig.json*

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "outDir": "./Scripts/dist/",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "module": "commonjs",
        "target": "es5",
        "lib": ["es5", "es6", "dom"],
        "jsx": "react"
    },
    "include": [
        "./Scripts/src/**/*"
    ]
}
```

*Default.aspx*

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    ...
</head>
<body>
    ...

    <div id="example"></div>

    <!-- Dependencies -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./node_modules/react/umd/react.development.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./node_modules/react-dom/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

    <!-- Main -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./Scripts/dist/bundle.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

**TL;DR**

If I change the path in only the following locations, my source map breaks:

*webpack.config.js*

```
context: path.resolve(__dirname, '[Scripts/]src'),
output: {
    publicPath: '/[Scripts/]dist/',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './[Scripts/]dist')
}
```

*tsconfig.json*

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./[Scripts/]dist/"
},
"include": [
    "./[Scripts/]src/**/*"
]
```

*Default.aspx*

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="./[Scripts/]dist/bundle.js"></script>
```

What else do I need to change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I tried browsing to the map file directly, I got an 500.19 config error:

> This configuration section cannot be used at this path. This happens when the section is locked at a parent level. Locking is either by default (overrideModeDefault="Deny"), or set explicitly by a location tag with overrideMode="Deny" or the legacy allowOverride="false".

Looking in my Web.config file, I noticed we had the following config section:

```
<location path="Scripts">
  <system.webServer>
    <security>
      <authentication>
        <anonymousAuthentication enabled="true" />
      </authentication>
    </security>
  </system.webServer>
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <allow users="?" />
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</location>
```

Removing that removed the issue.  However, we need this section to work with other parts of the application.  So instead I went to `<solutionDir>\.vs\config\applicationhost.config` and made the following changes:

- set `configuration/configSections/sectionGroup[name="system.webServer"]/sectionGroup[name="security"]/sectionGroup[name="authentication"]/section[name="anonymousAuthentication", overrideModeDefault="allow"]` (was `"deny"`)
- at the end, set `configuration/location[path=<webAppProject>]/system.webServer/security/authentication/anonymousAuthentication[enabled="true"]` (was `false`)

This satisfactorily resolves the issue.